# How to make subqueries in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two tables; listings and bids. I want to list all listings on which the highest bid is above 1 and below 10 using Ecto. See the code below for more information about the schema and query.

database schema

```
listings
  id
  name


bids
  listing_id
  amount
```

program.ex

```
Repo.all(
  from l in Listing,
  where: (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE listing_id = l.id) > 1 and
         (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE listing_id = l.id) < 10)
```

How would one go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a `group_by` / `having` query:

```rb
Repo.all(
  from l in Listing,
  join: b in assoc(l, :bids),
  group_by: l.id,
  having: (max(b.amount) > 1) and (max(b.amount) < 10)
  select: l)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) comes to the rescue:

```rb
join: l in Listing
where: fragment("
  ((SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE listing_id = ?) > 1 and
   (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bids WHERE listing_id = ?) < 10)
", l.id, l.id)
```